# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined

Tags: jquery

I have the following code and I keep getting this error:

The error seems to be on this line:

```
self.attr(rule.attr);
```

And here is the code

```
/* @type {Object} */
    var settings = $.extend({
        value: null,
        rules: [{
            'operator': null,
            'value': null,
            'attr': {},
            'callback': null
        }]
    }, options || {});
    var locale = $('html').attr('lang');
    return this.each(function () {
        var self = $(this);
        var elementValue = (settings.value) ? settings.value : self.text();
        elementValue = elementValue.replace(/[^0-9,\.-]/g, "");
        if (locale.indexOf("de") > -1) {
            elementValue = elementValue.replace('.', '').replace(',', '.');
        } else {
            elementValue = elementValue.replace(',', '');
        }
        elementValue = parseFloat(elementValue);
        if (!isNaN(elementValue)) {
            $.each(settings.rules, function (key, rule) {
                if (typeof rule.value === 'number') {
                    var operator = '>';
                    if (typeof rule.operator === 'string') {
                        operator = rule.operator;
                    }
                    if (eval(elementValue + ' ' + operator + ' ' + rule.value)) {
                        if (rule.callback) {
                            rule.callback(self);
                        } else {
                            self.attr(rule.attr);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong??

Comment: How are you calling the code? From the error message I would say that `this` is a collection of something that is not elements.

Comment: It's kinda a widget, so I am calling it $(this).baseTableWIdget({XXX}) and XXX is the set of rules

Comment: What is the context where you use that? Is `this` an element?

Comment: This is calling the cells on a table

Comment: Can you post more code of how you call it? My suspicion is that you actually don't call it on the cells, but something else. The error message tells us that `self` is the equivalent of `$(undefined)`, so the reference to the cell doesn't seem to reach the widget at all.